# How do I get Siri to "Remind me about this" for a page in Safari?

Tags: safari, siri, reminders

When I ask Safari to "Remind me about this" while a page in Safari is focused it creates the Reminder but with a link to Chrome. This happens regardless of if the the reminder is created on iOS or macOS. Safari is my default browser on macOS. How do I get the link in the reminder to open in Safari?

Comment: How is it a link to Chrome specifically? Does Chrome have its own URL scheme?

Comment: @seaturtle No, because it opens in Safari on iOS just fine. When the reminder is viewed in Reminders.app on macOS it shows the Chrome icon next to it. Also when the reminder fires one of the options is "Open in Google Chrome.app".

Comment: Weird. I figured it'd just be a plain link.

Comment: If you want to make the system temporarily forget it's installed, try this command in Terminal: `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -u <path to Chrome>` where _<path to chrome>_ is the location of the Chrome app. Then reboot. (Logging out and back in _might_ work, but it might not.) To undo, run it again without the `-u`.

Comment: It'll still show up in Spotlight and such -- it's still there -- but it shouldn't show up in Open With..., etc.

Comment: @seaturtle I just uninstalled Chrome, and then the link opened in Safari Preview. I uninstalled Safari Preview, and finally the link opened in Safari. But I need to have Chrome installed still. Safari is my default browser. If I click on a URL in the notes field of the Reminder (or any other app) it opens in Safari.

Comment: Just curious, does "Remind me about this" work in other browsers, or just Safari?

Comment: @seaturtle It works in my experience with any app including 3rd party apps that supports Hand Off. I've seen seen Hand Off with Chrome and trying "Remind me about this" in Chrome produces a blank reminder so it looks like Google hasn't built this functionality yet.

Comment: Neat. Did the `lsregister` command work, or did you have to actually uninstall it? Or did you not run it? (As a general rule, you shouldn't just take random Internet people like me at their word with Terminal commands, look the commands up first! :) Or run `man whatever`, it's the built-in manual.)

Comment: I didn't run it because I tried the uninstall method before you posted the comment but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Also, does rebooting help? A simple reboot fixes a lot of wacky things (like the sound output inexplicably not working :).

Comment: @seaturtle rebooting didn't help